# In CSS how can I make an element with "position: absolute" align left but also be contained right?

Tags: html, css, alignment, css-position, absolute

The goal is make the `absolute-position` element align left (achieved by default) but then also supersede the alignment to not extend out the right of `.row`.

- ***In Summary***: need to achieve a scaling solution so as the page grows [it aligns left] and shrinks [it aligns right].

```html
<div style="display: flex; position: relative; padding: 10px; background: deepskyblue; max-width: 350px">
  .row
  <div style="width: 150px">
    .col
  </div>
  <div style="position: relative;  padding: 10px; background: blueviolet; width: 150px">
    .col
    <label for="date">
      <b>
        Pick Date
      </b>
    </label>
    <div id="date_picker_listener" style="position: static; width: 100%; background: green">
      #date_picker_listener
      <input id="date" type="text" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy">
      <div style="position: absolute; width: 250px; height: 50px; background: red; left: 0">
        Absolute
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I got the solution!**

```html
<div style="display: flex; position: relative; padding: 10px; background: deepskyblue; max-width: 750px">
  .row
  <div style="width: 150px">
    .col
  </div>
  <div style="position: relative; padding: 10px; background: blueviolet; width: 350px">
    .col
    <label for="date">
      <b>
        Pick Date
      </b>
    </label>
    <div id="date_picker_listener" style="position: relative; width: 100%; background: green">
      #date_picker_listener
      <br>
      <input id="date" type="text" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy">
      <div style="position: absolute; width: 200px; height: 50px; background: red; right: 0; margin-right: calc(max(0px, ((100% - 200px))))">
        Absolute
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Set `position: relative` on the `#date_picker_listener` div to establish a containing block for absolute positioning.
2. Add `right: auto;` to the absolute-positioned div to ensure it doesn't extend out to the right when the page shrinks.

It should look like this

```
<div style="display: flex; position: relative; padding: 10px; background: deepskyblue; max-width: 350px">
  .row
  <div style="width: 150px">
    .col 
  </div>
  <div style="position: relative; padding: 10px; background: blueviolet; width: 150px">
    .col 
    <label for="date">
      <b>Pick Date</b>
    </label>
    <div id="date_picker_listener" style="position: relative; width: 100%; background: green">
      <!-- #date_picker_listener -->
      <input id="date" type="text" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy">
      <div style="position: absolute; width: 250px; height: 50px; background: red; left: 0; right: auto;">
        Absolute
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```